# How do I display the data properly from the snapshot to expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I finally managed to read the children of the node I wanted but I got another question, how do I display them on my screen properly. I tried to save the `snapshot` under `setToDoData` but I cannot bring it out

My code:

```
const SubScreen3 = ({route}) => {
  const paramKey = route.params.paramKey1
  
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  useEffect (() => {
    const starCountRef = ref(db, "food/" + paramKey);
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) =>{
      console.log(snapshot.val().Description);
      console.log(snapshot.val().Halal);
      console.log(snapshot.val().OH);
      console.log(snapshot.val().Location);
      console.log(snapshot.key);
      
      setToDoData(snapshot)
    })

     
  }, [])
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      
      <Text style = {styles.header}>{snapshot.key}</Text>
      
        
    
    </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen3
```

Here is my log from the console:
[image]

But when I run it, i get the output of `Snapshot cannot be found`

How do I solve this?

Update: I changed according to the solution provided but it gives me  `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Description, Halal, Location, OH}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` so i used the same method I did for another page to display multiple stuff but I have another issue which is `TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...todoData.map...')`

```
const SubScreen3 = ({route}) => {
  const paramKey = route.params.paramKey1
  
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  useEffect (() => {
    const starCountRef = ref(db, "food/" + paramKey);
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) =>{
      console.log(snapshot.val().Description);
      console.log(snapshot.val().Halal);
      console.log(snapshot.val().OH);
      console.log(snapshot.val().Location);
      console.log(snapshot.key);
      
      setToDoData(snapshot.val());
    })

     
  },)

  
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
       {
        todoData.map((item,index) => {
          return(
            <View key ={index}>
                <Text style = {styles.header}>{item.key}</Text>
                <Text style = {styles.header}>{item.val().Description}</Text>
                <Text style = {styles.header}>{item.val().Location}</Text>
                <Text style = {styles.header}>{item.val().OH}</Text>
                <Text style = {styles.header}>{item.val().Halal}</Text>
          
            <TouchableOpacity
        //onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SubScreen1", {paramKey:value})}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>How to go?</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        //onPress={}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Reviews</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      
                
            
            </View>          
            )
        })
      }
   </View>
 )
}
export default SubScreen3
```

Expected screen output: Something like this

[image]

What actually happen:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of the [DataSnapshot API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot.md#datasnapshot_class) seems to indicate that you want to call `snapshot.val()` to extract the data from the snapshot.  Personally, I would be storing that data in the state variable rather than the snapshot itself:

```js
setToDoData(snapshot.val());
```

Then in your JSX, you should be referring to the `todoData` variable, not the `snapshot` variable (which does not exist outside of the `onValue()` callback function.

Also, I would recommend NOT initializing your state variable to the value `[]`.  Simply leave the initialization blank, and check for a "falsey value" in your JSX.  Otherwise your code will not be able to distinguish between "has not received a value yet" (keep it as `undefined`) and "received a value but it has no data" (i.e. your query returns `[]`).

---

ANSWER TO THE EDITED QUESTION:

Your JSX has been updated to now use `todoData.map()`, meaning that `todoData` is expected to have an array.  But the code we gave in the earlier answer simply puts an object into `todoData`.

To support your newer JSX, you would modify the code where you put the data into the state variable such that you are appending to an array:

```js
setToDoData(curVal => {
  return [...curVal, snapshot.val()]
});
```

This new code now uses the second form of the "set state function" where you provide a callback function.  When the "set state function" runs, it will call the callback function passing the "current value" of the state variable.  From that, we expand it into a new array and append the new data from the snapshot.

Please, if there is a new problem, post a new SO post.  Editing posts like this is not advisable and becomes very hard to follow after just a couple of iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am having another issue after changing the code. I have updated the post with the new code and errors